# Use of @testSetup method in a Batch Class

Tags: apex, unit-test, batch

I have created a @testSetup method to create a data which generic. 
In my test method I am querying the data for some specific records and calling my batch class. The batch class is taking all the records instead of the specific records.

This the test class code:

```
@isTest
public Class VF_AssociateDealScanback_Batch_Test{
@testSetup static void dataSetup() {
        TestDataFactory testdata = new TestDataFactory();
        testdata.csVF_AssociateDealScanback_Batch();
        String generalRecordType =  Label.Scanback_Autobill;
        Account acc = testdata.parentAcnt(); //Create an Account Record
        List<Scanback_Page__c> listScanbackRecord = testdata.createScanback(5,acc.Id); //Create the Scanback Records   
        List<Deal__c>listDeal=testdata.dealCreation(18,acc.Id,generalRecordType);
    } 

static testMethod void testMethod1(){
 List<Deal__c> listDeal = new List<Deal__C>();
        Account acc = [Select id from Account limit 1];
        List<Scanback_Page__c>  listScanbackRecord = [Select id,Account__c,Scanback_Actual_Amount__c,Ad_Date__c,Deal_Title__c,Ad_Promo_Type_Number__c,Scanback_Processed__c,Units_Actual_Amount__c,Event_Title__c,RDWSyncStatus__c,Scanback_Unique_ID__c from Scanback_Page__c where Account__c =:acc.id]; 
        listDeal=   [Select id From Deal__c Where ((Off_Percent__c =: 0.3 AND Off_Percent_Operator__c =:'Greater Than Or Equal To' AND Page_Location__c =:'All Ad Pages'
            AND Deal_Sub_Type__c=:'Price Cut' AND Scan_Coverage_Description__c =:'Promo MD' AND Scan_Coverage__c=:20
            AND Geographic_Location_Description__c =:'Hawaii' AND Level_Type__c=:'SKU' AND Authorization_Date__c=:system.today())
            OR
            (Off_Percent__c =:0.43 AND Off_Percent_Operator__c =:'Equal To' AND Page_Location__c =:'All Ad Pages'
            AND Deal_Sub_Type__c=:'Price Cut' AND Scan_Coverage_Description__c =:'Promo MD' AND Scan_Coverage__c=:30
            AND Geographic_Location_Description__c =:'Hawaii' AND Level_Type__c=:'Vendor' AND Authorization_Date__c=:system.today())
            OR
            (Buy_Quantity__c = :20 AND Get_Quantity__c =:15 AND For_Amount__c=:'50% OFF' AND Multi_Offer_Operator__c=:'Greater Than Or Equal To'
            AND Page_Location__c =:'All Ad Pages' AND Deal_Sub_Type__c=:'Circular' AND Scan_Coverage_Description__c = :'Promo MD'
            AND Scan_Coverage__c=:10 AND Geographic_Location_Description__c =:'Hawaii' AND Level_Type__c=:'Primary SKU'))];

        for(Deal__c deal1: listDeal){
            system.debug('deal before executing6'+deal1.id);
        }
        Test.StartTest();
        VF_AssociateDealScanback_Batch obj = new VF_AssociateDealScanback_Batch();
        DataBase.executeBatch(obj);
        Test.StopTest();
}
}
```

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 1):

Merely running a SOQL query before instantiating `VF_AssociateDealScanback_Batch()` is not going to have any effect on the batch class's `start()` method, which is where the query locator or iterable that the batch runs on is generated.  As Phil W noted in a comment, it's best practice to test your classes the way they will run in production. If your batch class needs to be able to run on different sets of data determined at run time, you should adjust your batch class, and then test scenarios that cover the different queries you might pass to it.

You can look at [this Q&A](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/103223/passing-parameter-to-batch-apex) to see how to pass a parameter into a batch class constructor - you could have a constructor that allows you to pass in your query as a string, and another that uses a default query for the `start()` method.

So the beginning of `VF_AssociateDealScanback_Batch()` might look like this:

```
global class VF_AssociateDealScanback_Batch implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.Stateful {

    private String queryString;

    public VF_AssociateDealScanback_Batch(String qryParam) {
        this.queryString = qryParam;
    }

    public VF_AssociateDealScanback_Batch() {
        // use whatever query you have in the start() method now
        this.queryString = 'SELECT Id From Deal__c';
    }

    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        return Database.getQueryLocator(queryParameter);
    }
    // execute() and finish() methods as they are
```

and then your posted test method could look like this, and you'd have other test methods to cover the default query and any other passed-in query scenarios:

```
static testMethod void testMethod1(){
        Account acc = [Select id from Account limit 1];
        List<Scanback_Page__c>  listScanbackRecord = [Select id,Account__c,Scanback_Actual_Amount__c,Ad_Date__c,Deal_Title__c,Ad_Promo_Type_Number__c,Scanback_Processed__c,Units_Actual_Amount__c,Event_Title__c,RDWSyncStatus__c,Scanback_Unique_ID__c from Scanback_Page__c where Account__c =:acc.id]; 
        String listDealStr = 'Select id From Deal__c Where ((Off_Percent__c =: 0.3 AND' + 'Off_Percent_Operator__c = \'Greater Than Or Equal To\' AND Page_Location__c = \'All Ad Pages\ '
            + 'AND Deal_Sub_Type__c= \'Price Cut\' AND Scan_Coverage_Description__c = \'Promo MD\' AND Scan_Coverage__c= 20 '
            + 'AND Geographic_Location_Description__c = \'Hawaii\' AND Level_Type__c=\'SKU\' AND Authorization_Date__c= TODAY) '
            + 'OR '
            + '(Off_Percent__c = 0.43 AND Off_Percent_Operator__c = \'Equal To\' AND Page_Location__c =\'All Ad Pages\ '
            + 'AND Deal_Sub_Type__c=\'Price Cut\' AND Scan_Coverage_Description__c =\'Promo MD\' AND Scan_Coverage__c= 30 '
            + 'AND Geographic_Location_Description__c = \'Hawaii\' AND Level_Type__c=\'Vendor\' AND Authorization_Date__c= TODAY) '
            + 'OR '
            + '(Buy_Quantity__c = 20 AND Get_Quantity__c = 15 AND For_Amount__c= \'50% OFF\' AND Multi_Offer_Operator__c= \'Greater Than Or Equal To\' '
            + 'AND Page_Location__c = \'All Ad Pages\' AND Deal_Sub_Type__c= \'Circular\' AND Scan_Coverage_Description__c = \'Promo MD\' '
            + 'AND Scan_Coverage__c= 10 AND Geographic_Location_Description__c = \'Hawaii\' AND Level_Type__c= \'Primary SKU\'))';


        List<Deal__c> listDeal = Database.query(listDealStr);    
        for(Deal__c deal1: listDeal){
            system.debug('deal before executing '+deal1.id);
        }
        Test.StartTest();
            VF_AssociateDealScanback_Batch obj = new VF_AssociateDealScanback_Batch(listDealStr);
            Database.executeBatch(obj);
        Test.StopTest();
}
```

Comment: Personally, I disagree with having test-specific "production code". This test doesn't test the function of the batch as it would behave in production, but rather tests the batch in "test mode" which is rather defeating the point of the test. A test should ensure that the batch performs its whole job correctly. Such an approach is only reasonable if the batch is actually designed to operate with a configurable query. And then all constructors should be tested. I haven't downvoted because the other parts of the answer are reasonable.

Comment: I absolutely agree. The question didn't give enough detail to say whether the need to constrict the data that the batch operates on was test only. I'll edit my answer to give some caveats in that area.